# How to get $sce after getting Controller Scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

Newbie to `AngularJS`! I am getting the controller scope in Javascript with the below code.

**javascript**

```
var controller = document.getElementById("listModules");
var controllerScope = angular.element(controller).scope();

controllerScope.$apply(function(){
    controllerScope.newVariable = "test";    
}
```

**html**

```
<div id="listModules" ng-controller="myCtrl"></div>
```

This is working fine and I am able to create new variable and access it but I want to return HTML from a function which needs `$sce` inside the scope.

**access `$sce`**

```
controllerScope.$apply(function(){
    controllerScope.newFunc = function(htmlString){
       return $sce.trustAsHtml(htmlString)
    } 
}
```

I am stuck here to access `$sce`. Any Ideas?

Comment: Can you post the html where the listModules id is.
Also, Why don't you use the angularjs regular way?

Comment: Would have to inject `$sce`. Where are you running this code? Seems strange to need to do this the way you are doing it